# How can I use waitForElementVisible without reporting the result to the console?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, nightwatch.js

Using nightwatch.js how can I wait for an element to load without the result printing to the console?

I do not want waits to appear in my reports, only normal assertions.

The following code will output 'Waiting for settings menu to load' to the console. If no custom message is used, the default message is 'Element #editMenuContentsButton was visible after xxxx milliseconds':

```
/**Clicks the settings menu and logs the action.
 * @method clickSettings
 */
clickSettings: function () {
    this.waitForElementVisible('@settingsSettings', 5000, 'Waiting for settings menu to load');
    this.click('@settingsSettings', function () {
        testUtil.logAction('Click Gallery settings menu');
    });
    this.api.pause(1000);
    return this;
}
```

Comment: can you show your code what you have

Comment: you can refer to my answer in another question : https://stackoverflow.com/a/45637769/8444504

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this by simply commenting out the following code in the waitForElement.js file (found in: lib/api/element-commands)

```
WaitForElement.prototype.pass = function(result, defaultMsg, timeMs) {
this.message = this.formatMessage(defaultMsg, timeMs);
//this.client.assertion(true, null, null, this.message, this.abortOnFailure);
return this.complete(result);
};
```